# Can I Get An Action's Url Through Reflecting the DLL of a .Net MVC Website?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection

As the title.

So far I could get all controllers and actions info, like this

```

```
var asb = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath);
var ctrlDescs = from ctrl in asb.GetTypes()
                where ctrl.BaseType != null && ctrl.BaseType.Name == "Controller"
                select new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(ctrl);
foreach(var ctrlDesc in ctrlDescs)
{
    var actionDescs = desc.GetCononicalActions();
    //get actionName or something else...
}
```

```

But how can I build the url of an action? Should I implement a url parser myself to parse it? If so, where should I get the info such like "Area" of an controller?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for @Alex Sikilinda 's answer but the point is -- sorry I didn't make it clear -- the code is running individually from the website which I reflected those actions and controllers from. So anything like `Url.Action("actionName")` is not what I want, just as you said, the UrlHelper is obviously running on **current** Route system -- which is not those code I mentioned above running on

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use reflection to get an action's url, just use `UrlHelper` class in a controller or a view (Url is a property in the Controller class). The most common used overloads of the method are:

```
Url.Action("ActionName");
```

and

```
Url.Action("ActionName", "ContollerName");
```

But if you are bound to use reflection you can try passing an action's name fetched by reflection to the second method. But I belive UrlHelper uses current Routes sytem so I'm not sure it will work. Also you should remove prefix "Controller" from controller class name, because the method is supposed to be invoked without this prefix.